# Simple question on a quotient space of real projective space

Tags: general-topology, geometry

A silly little detail I am unable to work out on my own that is needed for a bigger thing...

I am quite convinced that the quotient space $\mathbb{R} \text{P}^{n} / \mathbb{R} \text{P}^{n-1}$ (where $\mathbb{R} \text{P}^{n-1}$ is included in $\mathbb{R} \text{P}^{n}$ in the standard way) is homeomorphic to $S^n$ on the grounds that it "makes sense" thinking about it geometrically in the case of $n=2$. Nevertheless, I am unable to actually construct a proof of the proposition.

If it is true, then this should be a standard result. Alas I cannot find it looking around. Anyone able to help me?

Comment: Do you know what the cell structure on $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is? If so, then this should be immediate. If not, consider $S^n/S^{n-1}$ and think about what you're left with, and what the antipodal identification does to this (you get a wedge of two $S^n$ that get identified with each other so you're left with one copy of $S^n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}\newcommand{\Vecx}{\mathbf{x}}$Consider the continuous mapping $\Vecx \mapsto (\Vecx, \sqrt{1 - \|\Vecx\|^{2}}$ from the closed unit ball in $\Reals^{n}$ to the "upper hemisphere" $H^{+}$ of the unit sphere in $\Reals^{n+1}$. Projection from $\Reals^{n+1}$ minus the origin sends $H^{+}$ onto $\Reals\Proj^{n}$, identifying antipodal points on the boundary. The mapping induced on the unit ball by quotienting out the projective hyperplane $\Reals\Proj^{n-1}$ collapses the boundary sphere to a point. This composite mapping is a continuous bijection on a compact Hausdorff space, so is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Real projective $n$-space can also be realized as a unit $n$-sphere mod $\pm 1$. Define a map $\sigma$ on the unit $n$-sphere by $$\sigma(x_0, \ldots, x_n) = (x_0^2, x_0 x_1, \ldots, x_0 x_n).$$ Then $\sigma$ is $\pm 1$ invariant and therefore well defined on projective $n$-space. As a projective map, $\sigma$ is injective on the complement of the projective $(n-1)$-space $x_0=0$, which it maps to $0$.  The image of $\sigma$ is the sphere of radius $\tfrac12$ centered at $(\tfrac12, 0, \ldots, 0)$.  So $\sigma$ identifies the quotient with a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

We can realize $\mathbb{R}P^n/\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} = * \cup_{\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}} \mathbb{R}P^n$ but also $\mathbb{R}P^n = \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$. Pasting together these two pushouts yields $\mathbb{R}P^n/\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \cong * \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n \cong S^n$.

(Sorry for being lazy to draw TikZ diagrams here on MSE.)

Comment: Well, Andrew D. Hwang did solve the problem for me a little over two years ago, but, hell, I'd rather live in a world with too many correct answers than too few! Enjoy your upvote, mate! :P